# best practice to set values of select tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

for example - a profile page - users want to change some values in select tags
you cannot say - `<select id='lorem' value='ipsum'>`
you must go to javascript -  `$('#lorem').val('ipsum')`
is this really true ?
is there any better practice - if you have a lot of select tags ?
btw - why html developers made this like this - there must be some strong reason

Comment: To my knowledge, dynamic change in html (without page reloading) must be done with Javascript code, This is basic purpose of javascript. But if you tell us more information about your final purpose maybe we could bring you a better way.

Comment: @MOWebCreation - `<input value='ipsum'` - this is not a dynamic change. Final purpose - to set the values normally, without javascript, because I have 9 select tags on page

Comment: you want to pre-set the "selected" value of a select dropdown on page/html generation?

Comment: check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes => `selected`

Comment: @MarianTheisen - there is no solution on your link

Comment: I think task is: selected items need to will be choosed from profile settings

Comment: Hello, the select itself does not have value attribute, the select has option tags as children which have value attributes, so what you want is just __text input__

Comment: @qadenza the solution would be to mark the option to select with the `selected` attribute. just read the docs. IF that is what you're trying to do => see my question before.

Comment: maybe it's best (the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774858/how-to-choose-select-option-with-javascript

Comment: @johnSmith - text input is not suitable in many cases

Comment: @DaniilLoban - I don't need a selected index in database, but a selected value

Comment: @qadenza a user can change the selects value by clicking on it and select an option! This is what selects are made for, pls explain what different you want

Comment: @qadenza of course I understand, you want to set 9 options on page by some data. is not it? I said that  $('#lorem').val('ipsum') - is OK

Comment: @johnSmith - I have some data about each user in database. Those data are from registration form. That form has select tags. Now, user want to change some data on his profile. Tha data need to be presented on select tags. It would be normal to do that using value attribute, like in any other input - without javascript

Comment: @DaniilLoban - `$('#lorem').val('ipsum')` - is not ok. It is a shame for html developers. Normal way is using value attribute in html

Comment: I don't use jQuery:)

Comment: @qadenza What kind of `<select>`-tags does the registration form have, and how are you fetching the results of your database-query?  What exactly are you trying to achieve with the results?

Answer (score 2):

Your "question" really embodies multiple questions, hence I divided my answer into multiple sections.

## `<select>` and `<option>`

To select an `<option>` of `<select>` initially, add the `selected`-attribute to `<option>`. Selecting an `<option>` makes the `<select>` have the value of the selected option.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var code = document.querySelector('code');

select.addEventListener('change', () => code.textContent = select.value);
code.textContent = select.value;
```

```css
body {display:flex;align-items:center;gap:0.5rem}
code {padding:0 0.2rem;background:lightgray}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="first">First option</option>
  <option value="second" selected>Second option, initially selected</option>
  <option value="third">Third option</option>
</select>

<span>Select's 'value': <code></code></span>
```

Giving `<select>` a `value`-attribute will be ignored by the browser-engine, since HTML5 doesn't specify the `<select>`-tag to have a `value`-attribute.
**Note:** The HTML-attribute `value` and the JavaScript property `.value` are not necessarily related to each other.

See this example for reference:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var code = document.querySelector('span > code');

select.addEventListener('change', evt => {
  code.textContent = evt.target.value;
});
code.textContent = select.value;
```

```css
body {display:flex;flex-flow:column;align-items:flex-start;gap:0.5rem}
code {padding:0 0.1rem;background:lightgray}
```

```html
<div>
  <code>&lt;select&gt;</code> has the attribute <code>value="from-select"</code>.
</div>

<select value="from-select">
  <option value="from-opt1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="from-opt2">Opt2</option>
</select>

<span>Select's 'value': <code></code></span>
```

To change the *value* of an `<option>` dynamically, you would have to use JavaScript.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var option = document.querySelector('option');
var code = document.querySelector('code');

// Ignore; update 'pre.textContent' when changing 'value'
option.setAttribute = function(name, value) {
  HTMLElement.prototype.setAttribute.call(this, name, value);
  if (name === 'value') code.textContent = value;
};

// How to change the 'value'-attribute using JS
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  option.setAttribute('value', input.value);
  input.value = '';
});
```

```css
body {display:flex;flex-flow:column;align-items:flex-start;gap:0.5rem}
code {padding:0.1rem 0.2rem;background:lightgray}
```

```html
<span>
  <input>
  <button>Change value of 'Option'</button>
</span>
<select>
  <option value="initial-value">Option</option>
</select>

<span>Option's value: <code>initial-value</code></span>
```

## Regarding "why html developers made this like this"

Paraphrased: *Why can't HTML change its markup on its own?*

Reason is, HTML was initially created for scientific documents served via the internet.
Since the internet is by nature a web of interconnected, potentially completely different devices, HTML had to be as unspecific and "device-agnostic" as possible, to allow rendering it on virtually *any* device that has a display.

For that reason, any further resource (e.g. stylesheets, scripts, images) should only be optional for the rendering of the HTML, as the HTML should be renderable "as is".
HTML should also be backwards-compatible, meaning that future changes to the HTML specification should in no way hinder the serving of the HTML. That means, any unknown... thing, basically, will be ignored by the rendering engine (todays browsers) so that all the then-existing features can still work as intended.

Initially, HTML was not intended to have any further functionality than serving static content. However, over the last few decades, the internet has had its "boom" of technological advancement, and now, JavaScript is *de facto* part of any browser-engine and website, enabling them to have advanced functionality and be interactive.

The internet is in a state of ongoing development, and always will be. Neglecting the new state of the internet and its specification (e.g. for the browser-engines, etc.) would mean that one is not moving with the times, withholding new, modern and current information and knowledge from oneself, essentially leaving one behind.

"Tradition" is difficult to find in any technical field, as new advancements and discoveries are simply spoken part of them.

To learn more about the roots of the internet (even though the video is thematically about CSS) I recommend watching [MDN's video about why CSS is weird (and how HTML came to be)](https://youtu.be/aHUtMbJw8iA).

## Regarding your "question" ...

as you have further explained in the comments:

> I have some data about each user in database. Those data are from
> registration form. That form has select tags. Now, user want to change
> some data on his profile. Tha data need to be presented on select
> tags. It would be normal to do that using value attribute, like in any
> other input - without javascript

You could do it two ways:

1. Create a `<form>` with one field for each user-data. With this, you have two more options:

   1. Prepare the fields to hold their current data. The user can then submit his changes easily.
   2. Leave the fields empty. If a field is empty after submission, ignore the proposed "change".
2. Let the user select what data to change one at a time. Again, two more options to achieve this:

   1. Fetch the current data for that field. The user can change it and then submit it easily, again.
   2. Let the user enter the new data anew, then submit it.

Here is a simple example of how the HTML for option 2.2 could look when implemented:
**Note:** I changed the `<button>`'s default type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` for demonstration-purposes.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var input = document.querySelector('input');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(`Would change user-data '${select.value}' to the value '${input.value}'.`);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="address">Address</option>
    <option value="email">E-Mail</option>
  </select>
  <input>
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but... but... but... - `<select id='lorem' value='ipsum'>` - what is the problem for developers to make this in html ?

Comment: @qadenza As you can see for yourself in my example above: Giving `<select>` a `value`-attribute does nothing. If you want to set the current value the selection should have, you would have to select the corresponding `<option>`.

Comment: as I explained more times above - my data is inside a database  - means - `<select id='lorem' value='<?php echo... ?>"'>` - and it is not possible with options

Comment: @qadenza What exactly are you trying to achieve when using the `value`-attribute in `<select>`? And why exactly is it not possible to use `<option>`? Perhaps elaborate what kind of data you are getting, and how you want to display it to the user. I'm starting to think that perhaps `<select>` isn't the right tag you are looking for.

Comment: Scenario is very simple - on registration form user choose some values using select tag. So if he wants to change the data - on profile page - I must provide a select tag and set a proper value given from database

Comment: @qadenza You should edit your question to incorporate your final goal. That would help not only me but all the others as well a lot. And please in as small steps as possible.